# Is evaluate or $! sufficient to WHNF-force a value in a multithreaded monadic context, or do I need pseq?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, parallel-processing, strictness

The following seems to work (as in: it keeps saying `Surely tomorrow` every second)

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

import Control.Exception (evaluate)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    godot <- newEmptyMVar
    forkIO $ do
        g <- evaluate $ last [0..]
        putMVar godot g
    let loop = do
        threadDelay $ 10^6
        g <- tryTakeMVar godot
        case g of
            Just g -> return ()
            Nothing -> putStrLn "Surely tomorrow." >> loop
    loop
```

This uses [`evaluate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:evaluate) to ensure `last [0..]` is actually forced to WHFN before filling the `MVar` – if I change the forked thread to

```
    forkIO $ do
        let g = last [0..]
        putMVar godot g
```

then the program terminates.

However, `evaluate` uses `seq`. In the context of deterministic parallelism, it's always emphasized that `seq` is not sufficient to actually guarantee evaluation order. Does this problem not arise in a monadic context, or should I better use

```
    forkIO $ do
        let g = last [0..]
        g `pseq` putMVar godot g
```

to ensure the compiler can't reorder the evaluation so `tryTakeMVar` succeeds prematurely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `pseq` is to ensure that after the parent thread sparks a computation with `par`, it does not immediately proceed to try to evaluate the result of the sparked computation itself, but instead does its own job first. See [the documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/parallel.html#annotating-pure-code-for-parallelism) for an example. When you're working more explicitly with concurrency, you shouldn't need `pseq`.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not totally wrong, evaluating `last [0..]` to WHNF would take an infinite amount of time, because WHNF for an `Int` means that you know the exact number.

`putMVar` will not start executing before `last [0..]` is evaluated to WHNF (which as we know takes forever), because `putMVar` will need the `RealWorld`-token (`s`) returned by the call to `evaluate`. (Or to put it more simply: `evaluate` works. It finishes only after evaluating its argument to WHNF.)

```
evaluate :: a -> IO a
evaluate a = IO $ \s -> seq# a s
--                     this    ^

putMVar (MVar mvar#) x = IO $ \ s# ->
--           which is used here ^^
    case putMVar# mvar# x s# of
--         is needed here ^^
        s2# -> (# s2#, () #)
```

where `seq#` is a GHC-prim function that guarantees to return `(# a, s #)` only after evaluating `a` to WHNF (that's its purpose). That is, only after `a` is evaluated to WHNF, `s` can be used in the call to `putMVar`. Although these tokens are purely imaginative ("RealWorld is deeply magical..."), they are respected by the compiler, and the whole IO-monad is built on top of it.

So yes, `evaluate` is enough in this case. `evaluate` is more than `seq`: it combines IO-monadic sequencing with `seq#`-sequencing to produce its effect.

---

In fact, the `pseq` version looks a bit fishy to me, because it ultimately depends on `lazy`, where `evaluate` ultimately depends on `seq#` and monadic token-passing. And I trust `seq#` a bit more.